# How to select upper level element?

Tags: css

I need to select an upper element from child one by logic below. I understand that pseudo class comparison is on the same level but how to get upper selector with lower level
`input:checked ~ .input-sibling .parent-of-input-sibling { }`

Comment: Use [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to increase readability of your question

Comment: Second example does not work because you are _selecting_ children elements

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions here. First is to use [:has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class. not a complete support yet, it's fairly new, but should work in all of the major browsers  but MF.

```
.parent:has(> input:checked)
```

Alternatively you could make use of the [focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) pseudo-class. But in this case it's limited to just parents that have focused (not checked) descendants.